# Is there a way to set this header text on the "center-left"?

Tags: css, html, position

Is there a way to set the header text to the "center-left" instead of center or left.

Thanks in advance.

---------------200px--------------->

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div style="background-color:red;width:200px;text-align:center"> <!--"text-align: center-left"-->
      <div style="">
        header
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Daimos I'm trying to put the header on the 1/4 of the header from left to right

Comment: There is no such a think as center-left ....Most likely you want `float: left`

Comment: @DavidVotrubec but is there a hack, to align the text where I want?

Comment: @Calne Then measure it in javascript, divide the value by 4 and assign it as `margin-left` to header

Comment: @DavidVotrubec if you write it as an answer, I'd be glad to mark it as the answer

Comment: @Calne You don't need JS for this. Please see my answer and see if that suits your needs. Second snippet, FYI!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps;

```css
.header{
margin-left:-25%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div style="background-color:red;width:200px;text-align:center"> <!--"text-align: center-left"-->
      <div style=""class="header">
        header
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems to be exactly what the OP needs

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center it on the left 50% of the screen? If so, this is it:

```css
.left-center {text-align: center; width: 50%;}
```

```html
<div class="left-center">Left Center</div>
```

Or if it is `1/4`th of the screen, then this would work:

```css
.left-center {text-align: center; width: 25%;}
```

```html
<div class="left-center">Left Center</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, or you center text or put it on the left side. No other ways.
If you want to make margins, use div like that:

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align:left">
your text
</div>
```

50% is for example, try it. You can also use margin or padding property, read about it.